# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' - Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get elements from my json response , however i am getting an error

> > 'str' object has no attribute 'get'.

What could be wrong in my code please help

```
        dataform = json.loads(job.body)
        data = json.dumps(dataform)

        logger.debug(data)
        logger.debug(data.get('number').strip())
```

My Reponse is below

```
{"shop_id": "23823addsf33sdfdlladioiddf", "user_id": "1", "number": "440239023011"}
```

Comment: `data = json.dumps(dataform)` creates a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.dumps` turns you dictionary into a string. After applying it, you have something like

```
data = "\{\"shop_id\": \"23823addsf33sdfdlladioiddf\" ..."
```

So, it's not a dictionary anymore, it's a string that looks like a dictionary. That's why you get the error. You should probably apply `get` to the previous line.

Comment: how do i get the element from data then and not dataform ? i want to access the json element

Comment: @MichaelAnaman: impossible to know, depends on the structure of you object. It could be by applying get to the `job.body` directly, but just guessing

Comment: "it's a string that looks like a dictionary. " => actually, to be exact, it's a string representing the JSON version of the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you get `str` after `json.dumps()`.

```
In [2]: json.dumps({"a": 1})
Out[2]: '{"a": 1}'
```

`dataform.get('number')` will work